# Cargar valores de un csv en un objeto de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un csv de donde quiero extraer los valores de cada linea(row):

```
 worker_name,department,hiring_manager
   Albert Eine,Dept 11,Rob Tomas
   Eddie Stein,Dept 10,Seth Lowe
   Jim Wayne,Dept 12,Noel Gilligan
```

y deseo meterlos en el objeto de una clase , tengo la idea de tener un metodo en la que tenga un bucle y por cada linea del csv crear un objeto, un objeto que se llame WorkerDatos, por lo que lei cada vez que inicialize el metodo puedo crear un objeto conteniendo los datos de cada trabajaddor, estaba pensando en la clase tener un arreglo(array) dinamico o usar colas y cada vez que cargue el objeto hacer push al final del arreglo un nuevo objeto.

tengo la idea pero soy nuevo en programacion orientada a objetos y en estructuras de datos , inclusive hice un codigo que funciona pero no la solucion ideal ya que no uso lo antes mencionado, cualquier ayuda sera agradecida.

Comment: ¿Dónde están las comas del CSV (Comma Separated Values)?

Comment: lo que puse en la pregunta era solo un ejemplo pero ya modifique para que se vean las comas @CandidMoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para redondear el ejemplo, vamos a leer los datos y poblar una lista de empleados.

```
empleados = []
```

Cada empleado es un objeto tipo `Persona` con tres datos: nombre, depto y jefe:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, depto, jefe):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.depto = depto
        self.jefe = jefe
```

Abrimos el archivo, descartamos la primera línea de encabezado (nombres de columna) y procesamos el resto.

Por cada línea, aplicamos `strip` para eliminar los *white space* sobrantes al principio y final de la línea. Luego aplicamos `split(",")` para separar la línea en una lista de tres valores (nombre, depto, jefe).

```
["Albert Eine", "Dept 11", "Rob Tomas"]
```

El objeto Empleado requiere tres parametros separados, y yo tengo una lista. Para separar la lista en sus partes, uso el operador "*":

```
with open("datos.csv", "r") as datos:
    header = datos.readline()
    for persona in datos:
        empleados.append(Persona(*persona.strip().split(",")))
```

Luego recorro la lista imprimiendo. Para esto uso `f-string`, que es un string donde encierro entre "{ }" expresiones Python válidas, las que son evaluadas y reemplazadas.

```
for empleado in empleados:
    print(f"Nombre: {empleado.nombre}, dept: {empleado.depto}, jefe: {empleado.jefe}")
```

produce:

```
Nombre: Albert Eine, dept: Dept 11, jefe: Rob Tomas
Nombre: Eddie Stein, dept: Dept 10, jefe: Seth Lowe
Nombre: Jim Wayne, dept: Dept 12, jefe: Noel Gilligan
```

Comment: gracias @Candid Moe creo que tu respuesta me va ayudar mucho a comprender lo que busco, mi ultima duda es por ejemplo me gustaria usar lo que esta adentro del **for empleado** en otro archivo python , quiero usar los atributos de empleado para una funcion , no estoy muy seguro de como usar eso en el otro archivo

Comment: @user964503. Lo mejor es que lo intentes tu mismo hasta donde puedas, y luego formules una nueva pregunta con lo que has logrado. De esa manera tendras una mejor respuesta, ya que tratar de resolverlo vía comentario no resulta.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te he entendido del todo, pero lo que quieres hacer es leer el contenido de un fichero .csv linea a linea, puedes usar el siguiente codigo:

```
with open('cloudbutton.py', 'r') as f:
    contenido = f.read()
    print(contenido)
```

O bien revisar las opciones que te da la libreria de `pandas` para trabajar con `dataframes`, suelen ser muy populares por su facilidad de implementación. Espero des con lo que estas buscando o nos comentes más detalles de lo que quieres realizar. ¡Saludos!

Comment: que tal @Ricardo J. Martínez Suástegui , gracias por tu ayuda, en realidad no tengo problemas para leer el archivo, tanto como la forma que me pusiste o con pandas, mi problema va mas al uso de programacion orientada a objetos , no estoy seguro con una clase como crear un objeto por cada vez que mande llamar a la clase que quiero usar , cada vez que inicialice quiero que se guarde una linea del csv , por ejemplo , la primera vez que guarde  "Albert Eine  Dept 11     Rob Tomas" y la que sigue " Eddie Stein  Dept 10   Seth Lowe" y asi, ojala me explique mejor, saludos igualmente.